# How to debug a failed restore of a Namecoin wallet?

Tags: backup, namecoin, rescan

I bought some Namecoins a while back. With the upcoming Merged Mining patch, I reinstalled Namecoin 0.3.24.63 on my newly formatted computer, copied my wallet.dat from my backup to the right folder, and ... can't seem to figure out how to view my funds.

I ran `namecoind -rescan`, and then:

```
> namecoind listaccounts

{
    "" : 0.00000000
}

> namecoind listreceivedbyaddress
[
]
```

Am I using the right commands here? Is my wallet corrupt/empty? Should I just wait for the blockchain to download? In Bitcoin, if I remember correctly transactions I made using a backup wallet were visible immediately (grayed out) even before the blockchain was downloaded. Any more suggestions?

**Update** - I have all the blocks.

> namecoind.exe getblockcount
>   19062

Comment: Wait for the blockchain to download.

Comment: @David - I have, no change.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is wait for the blockchain to download.  With most wallet backups/new installations of bitcoin or namecoin blockchain downloading is usually the issue.  Many people seem to get a little impatient and think the program is broken when it's really just the download taking a while.

Comment: OK, I have all the blocks. The output from `namecoind.exe getblockcount` is 19062.

Comment: I would confirm that the wallet.dat was placed in the correct folder.  One option is to place it wherever you want and do a -datadir=(folder path).

Comment: I started the namecoin client, went to c:\users\_UserName_\AppData\Roaming\Namecoin and found a folder full of namecoin data, updated in real time. Then I copy-pasted my wallet.dat there, overriding the one that was there.

Comment: Then you need to run with `-rescan` again.

Comment: @David - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/how-exactly-does-rescan-work

Comment: And, I've got nothing. Is there another way to debug this? I'm begining to suspect my original copy of the wallet is corrupt in some way, or just doesn't include the transactions for some reason. How can I verify it's a legit namecoin wallet?

Comment: Namecoin wallets and Bitcoin wallets are essentially identical, they just have differently formatted keys. You could try opening the wallet.dat file with something like [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet) or any other pre-0.4 Bitcoin wallet tool for that matter.