# Help with missing transaction

Tags: client, protocol, import, rescan

I'm trying to learn how to programmatically interact with the Bitcoin protocol. I've, seemingly, successfully generated a private key, WIF, and public address with code. I used Coinbase to send .001 BT to [14egr6kfYY4xiSVPim2sJnED4t89Yvn8hQ](https://blockchain.info/address/14egr6kfYY4xiSVPim2sJnED4t89Yvn8hQ). I then used the Bitcoin-Qt debug console and issued

```
walletpassphrase <WIF> More
```

to import the address. The address has shown up in Bitcoin-Qt but the transaction is not appearing.

[image: address]

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would try the -rescan command line option.

Comment: As Nate said, the `-rescan` should fix this. See [How exactly does a rescan work?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/how-exactly-does-rescan-work) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, doing

```
Bitcoin-Qt -rescan
```

fixed the missing transaction.