# Stuck in the middle between unconfirmed transaction and empty wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, wallet-recovery

I initially set a low fee to one transaction, trying to cancel the transaction I runned bit coin core with -zapwallettxes and all transactions in bit coin core disappeared. I still can see the transaction unconfirmed in mempool, but cannot cancel it from my wallet because is no longer listed. I have tryed -bumpfee but the answer is "the transaction is not in your wallet". Now I really do not know what to do. The transaction is unconfirmed. I cannot bumb the fees , I cannot cancel it. I would like to recover those bitcoin and send it either to the destination or back to the source wallet.

Txid: 9e43c1a702acec274d9d2fc727f4e4693f13eacaeb8a8edaec76d622e7771be2

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

> **I [ran Bitcoin] core with -zapwallettxes**

The [Release Notes for Bitcoin Core 0.21.0](https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.21.0/) say

> The -zapwallettxes startup option has been removed and its functionality removed from the wallet. This option was originally intended to allow for rescuing wallets which were affected by a malleability attack. More recently, it has been used in the fee bumping of transactions that did not signal RBF. This functionality has been superseded with the abandon transaction feature.

I think that was released 2021-01-14, nearly three years ago.

---

> **Any suggestions ?**

1. If you have a wallet backup I suggest restoring it and using `abandontransaction`

   > `abandontransaction "txid"`
   >
   > Mark in-wallet transaction  as abandoned
   > This will mark this transaction and all its in-wallet descendants as   abandoned **which will allow**
   > **for their inputs to be respent**.  It can be used to replace "stuck" or evicted transactions.
   > *It only works on transactions which are not included in a block and are not currently in the mempool*.
   > It has no effect on transactions which are already abandoned.

   (my emphasis)
2. Possibly relevant? - [How exactly does -rescan work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1249/13866)
3. Whatever you do, use `backupwallet` first.

Comment: My bit coin core version was very old,and I have used -zapwallettxes before upgrading. I cannot abandon transactions because the answer is the "transaction is not in your wallet". I have upgraded bitcoin core now, but the wallet is empty. I can see old addresses but no transaction. Is there a way to see old transactions ?

Comment: Option 2 above.